# How can i edit pdf and put it inside zip during stream then download using IText and java?

Tags: java, stream, itext, inputstream

My use case is this:  when the client clicks download on a pdf, I want to edit/write some text on to the pdf using Itext pdf editor, then zip the pdf then let it download, All during the stream. I am aware of memory issue if the pdf is large etc. which won't be an issue since its like 20-50kb. I have the zipping during the stream before downloading working using byte array, now have to make the pdfeditor method also run before zipping, add some text then let the download happen.

Here is my code so far:

```
    public class zipfolder {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                System.out.println("opening connection");
                URL url = new URL("http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/form.pdf");
                InputStream in = url.openStream();
                // FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new
                // File("enwiki.png"));
                PdfEditor writepdf = new PdfEditor();

                writepdf.manipulatePdf(url, dest, "field"); /// where i belive i
                                                            /// should execute the
                                                            /// editor function ?

                File f = new File("test.zip");

                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("newform.pdf");
                zos.putNextEntry(entry);

                System.out.println("reading from resource and writing to file...");
                int length = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];// buffer for portion of data from
                                                // connection
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zos.close();
                in.close();
                System.out.println("File downloaded");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
         }

        public class PdfEditor {
            public String insertFields (String field, String value) {
                return field + " " + value;
                // System.out.println("does this work :" + field);
            }

            // public static final String SRC = "src/resources/source.pdf";
            // public static final String DEST = "src/resources/Destination.pdf";
            //
            // public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,
            // IOException {
            // File file = new File(DEST);
            // file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            // }

            public String manipulatePdf(URL src, String dest, String field) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("test");
                try {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
                    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
                    Item item = form.getFieldItem("Name");
                    PdfDictionary widget = item.getWidget(0);
                    PdfArray rect = widget.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
                    rect.set(2, new PdfNumber(rect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() + 20f));
                    String value = field;
                    form.setField("Name", value);
                    form.setField("Company", value);
                    stamper.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error in manipulate");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    throw e;
                }
                return field;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to keep the data in memory, *don't write to a `FileOutputStream`* but instead use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Use this stream as `manipulatePdf` parameter or return it or the `byte[]` extracted from it as method result.

Comment: Please don't use `gitlab.itextsupport.com` in production code!

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse i am not using any production code, simply testing ur itext since it has existing field and everything

Comment: yup been playing with byteArrayOutputStream for a while. Trying to make it work thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So playing with ByteArrayOutputStream, finally got it work. passing the input stream to 'manipulatepdf' and returning 'bytedata'.

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream manipulatePdf(InputStream in, String field) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("pdfediter got hit");

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytedata = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);

        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, bytedata);
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        Item item = form.getFieldItem("Name");
        PdfDictionary widget = item.getWidget(0);
        PdfArray rect = widget.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
        rect.set(2, new PdfNumber(rect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() + 20f));
        String value = field;
        form.setField("Name", value);
        form.setField("Company", value);
        stamper.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in manipulate");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
    return bytedata;
}

public String editandzip (String data, String Link) {
    try {
        System.out.println("opening connection");
        URL url = new URL(Link);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();

        System.out.println("in : "+ url);

        //String data  = "working ok with main";
        PdfEditor writetopdf = new PdfEditor();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = writetopdf.manipulatePdf(in, data);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        File f = new File("C:/Users/JayAcer/workspace/test/test.zip");


        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("newform.pdf");
        entry.setSize(ba.length);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(ba);


        zos.close();
        in.close();
        System.out.println("File downloaded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;

}
```

}